# How to remove specific lines from file with sed/awk or something else?

Tags: sed, awk, addition, lines

I have a file that i pull and push to a svn repository. I need to remove part of one file while pulling from the repository and add the same part when i push to the repository. This will be done by 'git svn fetch' and 'git svn dcommit' The related question: [How to setup gitattributes to filter part of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270243/how-to-setup-gitattributes-to-filter-part-of-a-file)

I need an sed or awk script to remove and add this:

```
GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
    Svn-Managed = True
    Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
EndGlobalSection
```

From this:

```
Global
    GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
        Svn-Managed = True
        Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|Mixed Platforms = Debug|Mixed Platforms
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|Mixed Platforms = Release|Mixed Platforms
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

EDIT:
With awk i can do this to get the specific part of the file

```
awk -v RS='GlobalSection' '/SubversionScc/ {print RS$0 RS} ' file
```

How do i revert this to get everything else except this part?
And how do i add this part after

```
Global
```

or before

```
EndGlobal
```

in the original file?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sed to extract a particular section.

```
$ sed -n -e '/GlobalSection(SubversionScc/,/EndGlobalSection/p' yourfilename > yoursvnsection
$ cat yoursvnsection
    GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
        Svn-Managed = True
        Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
    EndGlobalSection
```

And use sed to read that file back in.

```
$ sed '/^Global$/ r yoursvnsection ' < yourfilename
Global
    GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
        Svn-Managed = True
        Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|Mixed Platforms = Debug|Mixed Platforms
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|Mixed Platforms = Release|Mixed Platforms
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: How do i extract and remove the section?

Comment: Nevermind managed it myself:
$ sed -e '/GlobalSection(SubversionScc/,/EndGlobalSection/d' original > originalWithoutSection