# Can git ignore a specific line?

Tags: git, gitx

I'm using git to sync to phonegap while testing on the phone's native browser. As such I have the following line:

```
var isPhoneGap = false;
```

Obviously I change this when building, but is there any way I can set up git to ignore this one line or do I have to go and put it in its own file and ignore it that way?

I'm using Gitx and the terminal on OSX 10.6.

Comment: @user494461: Git filters is the way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16244970/520162

Comment: Can you not detect the enviroment and use an eniroment config file ?

Comment: In short: No. But I've written a preprocessor script that looks for certain commented code and removes it before publication to git. Check it out here: https://github.com/franklinchou/ahk_config/blob/master/preprocess.sh

Answer (score 136):

If your file is of a specific type, you can declare a [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316728/6309), that you can declare in a `.gitattributes` file (as presented in the "Keyword expansion" of "[Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)"):

[image: http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0702-tn.png]

```
*.yourType filter=yourFilterName
```

(you can even [set that filter for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5270243/6309), if you want)

Implement:

- `yourFilterName.smudge` (triggered on `git checkout`) and

  ```
    git config --global filter.yourFilterName.smudge 'sed "s/isPhoneGap = .*/isPhoneGap = true/"'
  ```
- `yourFilterName.clean` (triggered on `git add`)

  ```
    git config --global filter.yourFilterName.clean 'sed "s/isPhoneGap = .*/isPhoneGap = false/"'
  ```

Your file would appear unchanged on `git status`, yet its checked out version would have the right value for `isPhoneGap`.

---

Note: [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line/22171275?noredirect=1#comment89082965_22171275), [ohaal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210983/ohaal) and [Roald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6329629/roald) suggest to isolate the `sed` calls in a separate `helper.sh` script:

```sh
sed "s/isPhoneGap = .*/isPhoneGap = true/" "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. got it working. Do you know how to make `git diff or `git status`, ignore the filters though? So I can still see what is different? My use case is for debug logs... which eventually I want to delete... @jthill @VonC

Comment: @timh if the filter is working, git status or git diff shouldn't show anything.

Comment: it's a pity there is no simpler way in GIT. git ignore <filename> <linenumber> would be so handy!

Comment: @kiedysktos linenumber? What if the line number changes?

Comment: This worked great, but Windows users beware, the gitconfig is very picky with which characters it wants to hold, so when trying some semi-exotic regular expressions you may run into trouble. I ended up putting my sed-calls in a separate helper.sh file that I called from my gitconfig with `sh ".git/helper.sh"` making sure to pass through any parameters to sed with `"$@"` (I assume just the filepath is passed).

Comment: @ohaal Good point. Using a script is often easier in those cases.

Comment: `helper.sh` content will then be: `sed "s/isPhoneGap = .*/isPhoneGap = true/" "$@"`

Comment: @Roald Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC perhaps comments in code? Filtering seems also dangerous as it can fetch more lines with the same pattern

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira I agree: you need a pattern specific enough to pick only what you expect. Not always a guarantee.

Answer (score 55):

You can use

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [file]
```

to ignore the changes of one file that you don't want track. I use this solution when I need to have a file in the repository but this file have some parts that change that I don't need track always.

When the file have changes that are important you have to do this:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [file]
```

Also, see the [Git doc update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) for `--[no-]assume-unchanged` parameter.

> When these flags are specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated. Instead, these options set and unset the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths. When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, git stops checking the working tree files for possible modifications, so you need to manually unset the bit to tell git when you change the working tree file.

Comment: Will doing this still fetch the new version when I do git pull?

Comment: @Caffeine when you do git pull you get the last version that was commited, this will be the last before you change to '--assume-unchanged' the file.

Comment: I believe `--skip-worktree` is a better option for most purposes. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39583010/4233593

Comment: '[Assume-unchanged should not be abused for an ignore mechanism. It is "I know my filesystem operations are slow. I'll promise Git that I won't change these paths by making them with that bit… Especially, it is *not* a promise by Git that Git will always consider these paths are unmodified—if Git can determine a path that is marked as assume-unchanged has changed without incurring extra lstat(2) cost, it reserves the right to report that the path *has been* modified (…`git commit -a` is free to commit that change).](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqy4z5go1y.fsf@gitster.dls.corp.google.com/)'

Comment: this ignores updates to the entire file not a specific line

Answer (score 8):

Continuing https://stackoverflow.com/a/20574486/4935114, [@Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108554/mike) proposed to create a `pre-commit` hook which will `grep` in the staged files for the lines which one might want to ignore. The hook checks if those lines were staged. If so, it `echo`s a warning and it `exit`'s with code `1` so the commit process won't continue.

Inspired by [@Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20574486/4935114), I found myself using perhaps an improved version of his hook which **automatically** `reset`s (with the `-p` flag) the specific line which we want to ignore.

I'm not sure this hook will work for a situation where you have many files with this line to be ignored, but this `pre-commit` hook looks for a changed in this line in a specific file `buildVars.java`. The hook script looked like this when I tested it on my machine.

```
#!/bin/sh

# this hook looks for lines with the text `var isPhoneGap = false;` in the file `buildVars.java` and it resets these lines to the previous state before staged with `reset -p`

if [[ $(git diff --no-ext-diff --cached buildVars.java | grep --count -e "var\ isPhoneGap[\ ]*=[\ ]*") -ne 0 ]]; then
    cat <<EOW
WARNING: You are attempting to commit changes which are not supposed to be commited according to this \`pre-commit\` hook
This \`pre-commit\` hook will reset all the files containing this line to it's previous state in the last commit.
EOW
    echo /$'\n'isPhoneGap$'\n'y$'\n'q | git reset -p
    # BONUS: Check if after reseting, there is no actual changes to be commited and if so, exit 1 so the commit process will abort.
    if [[ $(git diff --no-ext-diff --cached | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo there are no actual changes to be commited and besides the change to the variable \'isPhoneGap\' so I won\'t commit.
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

#### Explanation

What I did was echoing a control sequences which searches for the regex `isPhoneGap` during an interactive `reset` process. Thus emulating a user who presses `/` to search for `isPhoneGap`, presses `y` when asked if he wants to discard this patch and finally presses `q` to exit the interactive `reset`.

The interactive reversed patch process is documented here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#git-add-patch

---

**NOTE:** The above script assuming that the variable [`interactive.singleKey`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-interactivesingleKey) is `false`. If you configured yours to `true`, remove any `$'\n'` from the `echo` command right after the warning.

Answer (score 7):

Gitx should let you commit or ignore individual lines (you may know that already), but you'd have to do that every time you commit. I think it would be better to have a config file per deployment target (you can version those), and some runtime parameter for however you are starting the server (like `./myserver --config=whatever.js`).

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can kind of do it with [git filters](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_tt_filter_tt):

1. Create/Open gitattributes file:

   - <project root>/.gitattributes (will be committed into repo)
     OR
   - <project root>/.git/info/attributes (won't be committed into repo)
2. Add a line defining the files to be filtered:

   - `*.rb filter=gitignore`, i.e. run filter named `gitignore` on all `*.rb` files
3. Define the `gitignore` filter in your `gitconfig`:

   - `$ git config --global filter.gitignore.clean "sed '/#gitignore$/'d"`, i.e. delete these lines
   - `$ git config --global filter.gitignore.smudge cat`, i.e. do nothing when pulling file from repo

Notes:
Of course, this is for ruby files, applied when a line ends with `#gitignore`, applied globally in `~/.gitconfig`. Modify this however you need for your purposes.

Warning!!
This leaves your working file different from the repo (of course). Any checking out or rebasing will mean these lines will be lost! This trick may seem useless since these lines are repeatedly lost on check out, rebase, or pull, but I've a specific use case in order to make use of it.

Just `git stash save "proj1-debug"` *while the filter is inactive* (just temporarily disable it in `gitconfig` or something). This way, my debug code can always be `git stash apply`'d to my code at any time without fear of these lines ever being accidentally committed.

I have a possible idea for dealing with these problems, but I'll try implementing it some other time.

Thanks to Rudi and jw013 for mentioning git filters and gitattributes.

Answer (score 2):

A content filter driver is not a good solution. You may be able to hide this line from `git status`/etc but it's not really being ignored. As soon as you change the value, your working directory will be marked dirty even though the change may not be visible.

If you really want this line out of version control, changing it to a command line argument or placing it in an ignored include or build file may be the only practical means.

Comment: "As soon as you change the value, your working directory will be marked dirty even though the change may not be visible": it should not, if the clean script still restore the file in its original content.

Comment: That's what I had thought. I'm using GitExtensions and it will show the file as modified even tho the diff pane is blank. Possibly because clean filter isn't run until file check-in. Possibly because it's msysgit, not git-git. IDK, YMMV

Answer (score 2):

I think nobody has provided this way to work around the problem so, here's my technique. I keep logging/debugging/etc stuff in a single revision (actually, it could be multiple) in a private branch in my local repo. So, when I start a feature branch and I want to have all of my goodies (in `my-goodies` branch), I just do this:

```
git checkout my-feature
git cherry-pick my-feature..my-goodies # assuming both started from the same main branch, say, my-goodies started a few (or many) revisions back
```

Now I start working on the feature. When I am done, I rewrite history of the feature branch so that those revisions are gone:

```
git rebase -i @{u} # set all the goodies revisions to skip, save, and go
```

Now my branch is clean from all my goodies and I am fine to push anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this might be something that comes up in more than one line of your source.

I think it would be cleanest to have a .userbuildconfig file of some sort that you just include and have the defaults checked in. Then you can use [Carlos's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11430092/1270965) to mark that file alone as assume unchanged.  This way other changes to the file where you need to check the setting are not missed.

This can allow you to tune preprocessor macros locally (Or for java something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1813873/1270965).

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You can only ignore individual files (and more) since the lines in .gitignore matches file names and not file content. You have already mentioned the solution to this, i.e. ignore a single file that contains that content you want to ignore.

Comment: I agree, in my case it was sufficient and possible to simply include that content from an ignored file. So moving all ignorable settings. there. Also, I created a copy of that ignored file and added it to the index as reference, so the information on what's to be in that file won't be lost.