# sed regex to remove first comment of php file if the first comment contains a specific string

Tags: php, git, sed

I am running a commercial opensource CRM that is a pain to keep in VCS.  At the top of every file that isn't "open source"... they put a copywrite like so:

`/***********************************************************************************
 * Copyright (C) 2011-2015 Company Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * blah blah blah that changes every so often
 *
 ******a variable number of stars*****************/`

Whenever they change the copyright text/dates, every file I have looks like its changed in git.

**So my question**
How do I do this ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171275/140541 ) that will remove the copyright block... just so I don't have to see it in my git and don't have to worry about it when it changes?

Thanks!

**UPDATED question.**

I really need a sed statement that will turn this:

```
<?php 
/***************************************************************
 * Copyright (C) 2011-2015 Company Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * blah blah blah that changes every so often
 *
 ******************************/

some code 

/***
 * foo here
 */
```

Into this:

```
<?php    
/***************************************************************
 * some text here
 ******************************/

some code 

/***
 * foo here
 */
```

BUT it needs to only work if the first comment in a file has the word "Copyright" in it.

Comment: workaround: exclude their files from source control, and stuff your code into an external file, then it's just "file1" : `/* (c) useless junk */ include('the_real_code.php');`

Comment: Isn't the article you posted the answer to your question?

Comment: @Marc B.  its a large application with thousands of files.  I can't simply do that.

Comment: @ahoffner, yes, but what is the sed regex of how to do just the comment that has the copyright.  I suck at regex.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/vJ0wD4/1

Comment: @ahoffner no go... tested w/ sed on windows and linux.  It removes teh **** before and after / but not the text between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I say repeatedly - sed is NOT for anything involving multiple lines. That's what awk was invented to handle:

```
$ cat tst.awk
inCmt && /\*\// {
    if (cmt ~ /Copyright/) {
        sub(/\n.*/,"\n * some text here\n",cmt)
    }
    $0 = cmt $0
    inCmt=0
    done=1
}
!done && /\/\*/ { inCmt=1 }
inCmt { cmt = cmt $0 ORS; next }
{ print }
```

.

```
$ cat file1
<?php
/***************************************************************
 * Copyright (C) 2011-2015 Company Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * blah blah blah that changes every so often
 *
 ******************************/

some code

/***
 * foo here
 */

$ awk -f tst.awk file1
<?php
/***************************************************************
 * some text here
 ******************************/

some code

/***
 * foo here
 */
```

.

```
$ cat file2
<?php
/***************************************************************
 * blahblahbla (C) 2011-2015 Company Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * blah blah blah that changes every so often
 *
 ******************************/

some code

/***
 * foo here
 */

$ awk -f tst.awk file2
<?php
/***************************************************************
 * blahblahbla (C) 2011-2015 Company Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * blah blah blah that changes every so often
 *
 ******************************/

some code

/***
 * foo here
 */
```

Comment: @ghoti thanks but I had missed the requirement to only process comments if the contained the word `Copyright`. Updated now. Not as short but still sweet :-).