# ignoring specific changes inside files

Tags: git, bitbucket, talend

I'm using Talend Open Studio at work. We are working on best practices for using git with Talend source which is all xml under the hood.  Talend likes to change the modification date in some lines of underlying xml files and it clutters my SourceTree GUI with a bunch of changes that aren't really changes. How do i get sourcetree and/or git to ignore these changes without ignoring the entire file?

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can git ignore a specific line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line)

Comment: I haven't tested yet.  But the other post looks promising. Thanks mayo