# Can git ignore multiple specific line?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

How can multiple lines be ignored in git?
Or in other words: how to add multiple filters

This method works well for [a filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171275/11896815)

I added a filter that works fine, but I want to add a few filters, for several lines. 
If anyone knows please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have your single filter rewrite all the lines in question. Sed, for example, takes multiple "s/x/y/g" expressions on its command line. If you need more, just write your filter as a shell script, then you can do any text processing you like in that script.