# How to prevent some lines from going upstream

Tags: git, github

I am not well versed into GitHub and I've run into a problem that I don't know if I am solving correctly.

**My problem:**
I am trying to contribute to an open-source repository and I know by experience that my code will be revised, discussed and probably not accepted on my first try. So I would like to send the changes I made and leave my comments and annotations for myself so I can both use them for further development and spare the reviewer from reading unnecessary info.

My first idea was to make 2 branches, one with debugs and other without, but I would have to manually sync them every once in a while. This doesn't look like the *git way* of doing this and I am wondering if this can be made easier.

Comment: If you are using gitignore, this answer way help you [Can git ignore a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line)

Comment: What I do in cases like this is keep the logging/other-stuff-i-like on a single revision in a private branch so that when I want to bring it over into the branch I really want to work on, I cherry-pick it.... when I am done with the real branch, I rewrite it so that the revision is moved out.