# How to use an alternate go.mod file for local development?

Tags: go, local, serverless, go-modules

Currently I am working on an API which uses Serverless Framework with Go.

I'm using the Serverless-offline plugin for local testing.

This API depends on a few other repositories (which I also maintain), which I import using the `go.mod` file.

However I am having a hard time refining my developer workflow.

Currently, if I want to make changes in a repository which this API depends upon, I have to alter the projects `go.mod` to include [replace directives](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) for the purpose of testing, but then I'm having to manually change it back for deployment to production.

Basically **I'm looking for a way to include replace directives, which only get applied during local development**. How has everyone else dealt with this problem?

Bonus question: Is there any way to run Serverless offline in docker? I'm finding that serverless-offline running on the bare metal is causing inconsistencies between different developers environments.

Answer (score 7):

You can run `go` commands with an alternate `go.mod` file with the `-modfile` option:

From [Build commands](https://golang.org/ref/mod#build-commands):

> The `-modfile=file.mod` flag instructs the go command to read (and
> possibly write) an alternate file instead of `go.mod` in the module root
> directory. The file’s name must end with `.mod`. A file named `go.mod`
> must still be present in order to determine the module root directory,
> but it is not accessed. When `-modfile` is specified, an alternate
> `go.sum` file is also used: its path is derived from the `-modfile` flag
> by trimming the .mod extension and appending .sum.

Create a `local.go.mod` file with the necessary `replace` directive for development and build, for example, with:

```
go build -modfile=local.go.mod ./...
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this in Go 1.18 or later is using the new **Go workspaces** feature. See

- https://go.dev/ref/mod#workspaces
- https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces

Essentially, use `go work init` to create a `go.work` file, that can contain local replacement directives, outside the scope of your `go.mod`.