# Can I specify a replace directive elsewhere other than go.mod for sharing with other developers?

Tags: go, dependencies, go-modules

`go.mod`'s `replace` directive is a local configuration option, different developers could have the local module source in different locations.

It just feels wrong including this option in a file that has to be committed to a repo from which others can use the module (be it private or public).

**Is there a way to specify this somewhere else than in `go.mod`?**

Example:
https://github.com/Drean64/c64/blob/master/src/go.mod#L5

```golang
module github.com/Drean64/c64
go 1.18
replace github.com/Drean64/cpu6502 => ../../cpu6502/src
```

Comment: `replace` is part the `go.mod` syntax, so obviously you must use it within a `go.mod` file. Note also that `replace` [isn't meant *only* for local development](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace). You can replace with whatever other valid module. Indeed it makes little sense to commit a `go.mod` into a VCS with a local replace. In those cases you can use [an alternate go.mod for local development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68764637/how-to-use-an-alternate-go-mod-file-for-local-development)

Comment: Your instinct here is good. As @blackgreen says you can use an alternate go.mod. I think go 1.18 workspaces may also be useful here but I have not actually used go 1.18 yet.

Comment: Can I know why was this question voted to be closed? maybe I can improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace directive temporary solution when you want to use local modules but I prefer to use build flags, below `-modfile` is good and you can use it while building or running the program.

example : `go run -modfile=local.mod main.go`

```
-modfile file
        in module aware mode, read (and possibly write) an alternate go.mod
        file instead of the one in the module root directory. A file named
        "go.mod" must still be present in order to determine the module root
        directory, but it is not accessed. When -modfile is specified, an
        alternate go.sum file is also used: its path is derived from the
        -modfile flag by trimming the ".mod" extension and appending ".sum".
```

I do use replace directive only when needs a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

> different developers could have the local module source in different locations.

By using a relative path, you could reference a folder which is a submodule of your main repository project, which means all developer would benefit from the same local `replace` directive.

> Is there a way to specify this somewhere else than in go.mod?

It does not seem to be, the [`replace` directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) is linked to `go.mod`, and:

> `replace` directives only apply in the main module’s `go.mod` file and are ignored in other modules.

Comment: As you can see in my example, both `cpu6502` and `c64` are 2 independent modules, no one is a submodule of the other.
c64 uses cpu6502, but cpu6502 could be used by other modules too.