# How to ignore multiple lines of code in the same file type using gitattribute and git config?

Tags: git, gitattributes

As an extension of this [post: Can git ignore a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line), I am trying to ignore multiple lines in the same file type.

Is there a way to either;

- set multiple filters to the same `.gitattributes` filter for the same file or file types? (like below) OR

```
*.rs filter=filterA
*.rs filter=filterB

 // to something like
*.rs filter=filterA + filterB
```

- add multiple rules to the same filter in `.git/config`? (like below)

```
[filter "filterA"]
    clean = sed "/abc/d"
[filter "filterB"]
    clean = sed "/def/d"

 // to something like
[filter "filterC"]
    clean = sed "/abc/d"
    clean = sed "/def/d"
```

The above causes the last filter in `.gitattributes` to overwrite the changes made from the first filter. I have also attempted something like `clean = sed "/abc*def/d"`, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore entire lines my advice is to use `grep -v` instead of `sed //d`. The answers at the linked question use `sed` because they hide only parts of lines, a task for which `sed` is exactly suitable.

So 1st lets rewrite your two simple filters:

```
[filter "filterA"]
    clean = grep -v "abc"
[filter "filterB"]
    clean = grep -v "def"
```

Please be warned that if your placeholders `abc` and `def` contain regular expression metacharacters you need to escape them using backslash. Like `\*` — `grep` interprets this as a literal asterisk while `*` is a metacharacter. See [`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Now to the more complex filter: combine the two expressions into one complex regular expression:

```
[filter "filterC"]
    clean = grep -v "abc\|def"
```

`\|` separates branches in regular expressions in basic (default) `grep` syntax. In case of extended RE the syntax is

```
[filter "filterC"]
    clean = grep -Ev "abc|def"
```

Comment: thank you, super detailed and helpful! I liked your filterC examples, but couldn't seem to get it working. So I changed it to this `clean = "grep -v 'abc' | grep -v 'def'"` to get it done.