Get git to automatically ignore lines containing a specific string?
I wrote this program that helps me automatically put prints into a large codebase for debugging. Each line I add has /*&&==&&*/ on it so that the script can remove/edit these specific lines.
What would be nice would be to locally have git ignore any diffs that contain this substring in a line. This way I can switch branches/make commits etc while still keeping these prints in the codebase.
Is there a way to gitignore specific lines? And specific lines that contain a substring?

Not easily, and I recommend against going down that path. Instead, consider leaving the debugging code in place and turning it on and off with a compile flag or environment variable. Then it will be useful for everyone on the project. Most languages have logging and debugging libraries for this with minimal impact on performance.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171275/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+lines

@CalebK But hard to program, error-prone, and cannot be automatically distributed to other members of the team; .gitattributes can be distributed but not .git/config
